# Kotlin: lateinit property userDatabase has not been initialized when switching fragments

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have an activity with Three Tabs and Four Fragments. On one of the tabs (Profile tab), I have a fragment (ProfileFragment) that has a button to redirect the user to another fragment (EditorFragment) to edit the user's profile.

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {
   
 ...

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)

        val btn = v.findViewById<View>(R.id.editProfileButton) as Button

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            val fragment = EditorFragment()
            val fragmentManager = activity!!.supportFragmentManager
            val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)

           transaction.addToBackStack(null)
            transaction.commit()
        }
        return v
    }
```

The EditorFragment also belongs to the Profile Tab:

```
        class EditorFragment : Fragment() {
        
            private lateinit var userDatabase: DatabaseReference
            private var callback: AppCallback? = null
    
        fun setCallback(callback: AppCallback) {
            this.callback = callback
            userId = callback.onGetUserId()
            userDatabase = callback.getUserDatabase().child(userId)
        }


        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

            populateInfo(view)
        }

    
       fun populateInfo(view: View) {
        userDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
             ...
            }
```

When I give priority to the EditorFragment to open first, everything
goes well but when I am in ProfileFragment and try to use the button
to redirect to Editor Fragment, the app crashes.

ERROR:

```
lateinit property userDatabase has not been initialized
at com.example.app.fragments.EditorFragment.populateInfo(EditorFragment.kt:138)
```

Which refers to this line on EditorFragment populateInfo():

```
userDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
```

Aditional Information that may help:

- The button is functioning when I delete everything related to the
  issue.

Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MainCallback {
             
    private lateinit var userDatabase: DatabaseReference
    private var profileFragment: ProfileFragment? = null
    private var editorFragment: EditorFragment? = null

    ...

        navigationTabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        ...

            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                when(tab) {
                    profileTab -> {
                        if (profileFragment == null) {
                            profileFragment = ProfileFragment()
                            profileFragment!!.setCallback(this@MainActivity)
                        }
                        replaceFragment(profileFragment!!)

                        if (editorFragment == null) {
                            editorFragment = EditorFragment()
                            editorFragment!!.setCallback(this@MainActivity)
                        }
                        replaceFragment (editorFragment!!)
                    }
         ...


     fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
         supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
        .commit()
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you give priority to EditorFragment to open first your onTabSelectListener in triggered hence calling your *setCallBack* that initializes your database, when you open the ProfileFragment first it is not triggering your onTabSelectedListener hence it doesnt call your *setCallBack* and it doesn't initializes your database. Let me know if it helps you to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've been making tests to see if the Listener actually triggers and even when I call the editorFragment first and then navigate to profileFragment and click the button, the same error appears.